# Is it a good idea to write a full message to a NetworkStream, or to write sections of each message?

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, message

I was wondering to myself whether or not writing a full message to a NetworkStream would be better than writing each section of a message in multiple Write calls. For example, would writing the message in full like such...

```
    NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();

    byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a message.");
    ns.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
```

... be a better idea than writing like this...

```
    NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();

    byte[] message1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This ");
    byte[] message2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("is ");
    byte[] message3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("a ");
    byte[] message4 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("message.");

    ns.Write(message1, 0, message1.Length);
    ns.Write(message2, 0, message2.Length);
    ns.Write(message3, 0, message3.Length);
    ns.Write(message4, 0, message4.Length);
```

Is there also much difference in program performance or networking performance for each method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of networking it will be the same. But on the client you don't need to have the entire message loaded in memory if you use the second approach. This could be useful when dealing with really big volumes of data. For example let's suppose that you want to send huge files. You could read those files in chunks so that you never need to load the entire file contents in memory and send it in chunks to the network. Only one chunk will ever be loaded at a time in-memory on the client.

But obviously if you already have the entire message in memory don't bother and write it in one shot to the network socket.

Answer (score 4):

This gets tricky, and depends on how the socket is configured. What you Write does not not map directly to what is received:

- the NIC may have to split it into packets at transmission
- the socket/NIC may be configured to *combine* packets for tramsmission (reducing the actual network packets, but making it hard to be sure that you've sent what you think you have - it may be buffered locally)

Note in particular that `NetworkStream.Flush()` **doesn't do anything**, so you can't use that to push any last few bytes

A good compromise is to wrap the `NetworkStream` in a `BufferedStream`, and configure the `Socket` with `NoDelay = true` (disables local output buffering). The `BufferedStream` allows you to keep writing in any-size chunks (including individual bytes), without causing huge packet fragmentation; the `BufferedStream` will flush itself when it approaches a set size. However, and importantly, you now have access to the `BufferedStream`'s `Flush()` method which **will** empty the buffered data to the network; useful if having a complex back-fore conversation and need to know you've sent the end of your message.

The risk otherwise is that the client waits forever for a response (without realising it still has 3 bytes buffered locally, so hasn't sent a full request), and the server doesn't respond because it is still waiting for the last 3 bytes of a request. Deadlock.